# Cannot get system identifier in WPF

Tags: c#, wmi, system.management

I programming in WPF C# and trying to get the ProcessorID (or other system identifier). I have read through [MSDN - System.Management Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwd0y33x.aspx). I add the namespace, but it does not provide `ManagementBaseObject Class`.

```
using System.Management;

/* code */
System.Management.(there is no ManagementBaseObject)
```

Is System.Management only used in WinForms, and not WPF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will give you the processor id, given that you have added a reference to `System.Management`:

```
public static string GetProcessorID()
{
    var processorID = "";
    var query = "SELECT ProcessorId FROM Win32_Processor";

    var oManagementObjectSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);

    foreach (var oManagementObject in oManagementObjectSearcher.Get())
    {
        processorID = (string)oManagementObject["ProcessorId"];
        break;
    }

    return processorID;  
}
```

Comment: @KMC: You wouldn't have to, but as it is a method that is independent from any object state it makes sense. Also note, that the `System.Management` namespace is completely independent from whether your application is a console, Windows Forms or WPF application.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a reference to System.Management.dll

(Per the "Assembly" in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementbaseobject.aspx) for that class)

Answer (score 2):

There are some existing types with the `System.Management` namespace within `System.Core`, this is why you are seeing some types.

For `ManagementBaseObject`, however, you will also need to add a reference to `System.Management.dll` to your project.

Answer (score 0):

The code of Dirk might return a null object.
Please correct it in this way:

```
public static string GetProcessorID()
{
    string cpuid = "";
    ManagementObjectSearcher mbs = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select ProcessorID From Win32_processor");
    foreach (ManagementObject mo in mbs.Get())
    {
        var processorId = mo["ProcessorID"];
        if (processorId != null)
        {
            cpuid = processorId.ToString();
            break;
        }
    }

    return cpuid;
}
```